# One time URL for Form

Tags: visualforce, security

I am  currently working on a module to update lead/account information. I am having a link which is sent via email to users to update their profile. This url links to a visual force page. On click of this URL the user will provide more information which will be updated on the lead/account.
For security reasons I would like to make this link a single use link, so that the respective users cannot change the information once they have submitted the form.

I am not understanding how I can generate and process this URL. Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basic idea would be something like if user click save -- submit record for approval. Or just create custom object and put field there -- if page has been opened (and or something has happened) -> update field on that custom object, so those page would not be able to be opened again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a 'Submitted Form' checkbox field in the object (default value: false). 
In the constructor, query that field and display the page only if False and display a information/warning message if True.
When the user clicks on the 'Save' method, update field to True.

Please, let me know if you need more help.

Comment: hi Javier thank you very much that seems like the best solution. So does this mean that I will have to use jquery/javascript to implement the checkbox true/false functionality